# Ошибка create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentTyp при отправке файла на сервер

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос для того чтобы сохранить фотографию товара в ВК. фото заливается в три этапа: 1. получаю ссылку куда отправлять запрос отправляю методом POST фотографию и получаю её адрес 2. вставляю её в группу Проблема на втором шаге я не получаю адреса фотографии... то что фотографию отправляется на сайт точно, проверял на сайте, что возвращает POST запрос.

```
private static String postit3(String uploadUrl, String imagepath) throws Exception {
HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = builder.build();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);

MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
entityBuilder.addPart("file", new FileBody(new File(imagepath)));
// entityBuilder.addPart("fileb", new FileBody(fileb));
final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);


String inputLine;
StringBuffer response2 = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response2.append(inputLine);
}
reader.close();

// print result
System.out.println(response2.toString());
return response.toString();
}
```

`final HttpEntity entity = entityBuilder.build();` на этой строке почему то появляется ошибка:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.create(Ljava/lang/String;[Lorg/apache/http/NameValuePair;)Lorg/apache/http/entity/ContentType;
```

как исправить ?

Comment: Предусловие:

1. Пытаюсь отправить POST запрос для того чтобы сохранить фотографию товара в ВК. 

фото заливается в три этапа:

1. получаю ссылку куда отправлять запрос отправляю методом POST фотографию и получаю её адрес  

2. вставляю её в группу Проблема на втором шаге

Answer (score 0):

Поменяйте версию httpcore или httpmime. Ошибка вам говорит о том что `MultipartEntityBuilder` не содержит тот или иной метод.

Answer (score -1):

все было проще, не тот респонс возвращал

надо

```
return response2.toString();
```